# Are there any cases where single-cycle is better than pipelining?

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, mips

I've been asked by my professor

> When pipelining is better than single-cyle MIPS CPU's?

I actually answered "always", but I'm not sure that's the correct answer. Excluding an increase in design complexity, and the added complexity in handling hazards, from the point of performances doesn't pipelining always give better (**or equal**) results?

EDIT: I omitted I was talking about the MIPS architecture.

Comment: What would happen with a large pipeline if you had a lot of unpredictable branches in the code? (for a clue look at the performance per MHz of the pentium 4 Vs the pentium 3 CPUs from when Intel decided for marketing reasons that MHz mattered more than performance)

Comment: In the worst case, all of the branch predictions will fail. That means the pipeline needs always to be flushed, i.e. the instructions already in the pipeline have to be made "innocuous", i.e. transformed into NOP's. Yet, you're still having shorter clock cycles and you will insert instructions into the pipeline as soon as you know if the branch is to take or not, making the whole thing similar if not still faster than a single-cycle scenario.

Comment: For example, suppose that converting a single-cycle implementation to a five-stage pipeline allows you to double the clock speed, but that a conditional branch requires you to flush the pipe. If 20% of the instructions are conditional branches, the pipelined implementation is already reduced to the same performance as the original implementation.

Comment: @DaveTweed Could you expand more? I can't follow your math

Comment: If 20% of instructions require a pipeline flush and your pipeline has 5 stages then you will execute the first 5 instructions in 9 clock cycles, you then have to flush the pipeline which takes 1 cycle and you start again... So 5 instructions every 10 cycles or 2 cycles per instruction. If adding the pipeline doubled your clock speed then you end up being at exactly the same effective rate as a single cycle system only with a lot more silicon and a far higher power consumption.

Comment: See the edit I made to my answer below.

Answer (score 8):

It depends on what you mean by "performance". Pipelining generally improves throughput, measured in terms of results per unit time, but it increases latency — the time that elapses from the beginning to the end of any particular computation.

Sometimes the latter is more important than the former. In particular, if the code has lots of conditional branches with only small numbers of other instructions between them, the latency associated with deciding which way each branch will go makes it impossible to keep the pipeline filled with useful instructions.

---

For example, suppose that converting a single-cycle implementation to a five-stage pipeline allows you to double the clock speed, but that a conditional branch requires you to flush the pipe. If 20% of the instructions are conditional branches, the pipelined implementation is already reduced to the same performance as the original implementation.

A single-cycle machine uses every clock cycle, so at 1GHz, it takes 5 ns to execute 5 instructions​.

The pipelined machine runs at 2 GHz, so it decodes the 5 instructions in 5 clock cycles, or 2.5 ns. But it takes another 5 cycles (2.5 ns) until the result of the branch is known, during which no other instructions can be issued to the pipeline. It is only after the 10th cycle that the next useful instruction can be decoded, which means that this machine also took a total of 5 ns to execute those same instructions.

Comment: Not to mention that "added complexity" is not really a claim backed by OP – I'd doubt that, in the general case.

Comment: Why it increases latency?, at instruction level because of the overhead to implement it?

Comment: Latency always increases with pipelining, because pipeline registers always introduce a delay from input to output, regardless of the actual implementation technology.

Comment: @DaveTweed "... the latency associated with deciding which way each branch will go makes it impossible to keep the pipeline filled with useful instructions." Isn't a single-cycle still worse, since it *always* has parts of the CPU unused?

Comment: No, a single-cycle implementation never needs to waste clock cycles.

Comment: @giuscri: Pipelines introduce timing uncertainty that is not present in a single cycle architecture.

Comment: @DaveTweed Should I care? OK, I could waste clock cycles sometimes, but they're shorter so the net gain should still be positive

Comment: @PeterSmith I prefer having "better" performance sometimes, than always mean. Who cares about timing uncertainty?

Comment: @giuscri you seem to be working on the assumption that doubling the pipeline stages allows you to double the clock speed, that simply isn't true.

Comment: Who cares about timing uncertainty? Anyone building real time embedded systems.

Comment: @Andrew Starting from a single-clock cycle CPU with a clock cycle of 400ps, if I find how to split each instruction in my instruction set into two parts taking both ~200ps time to "execute" and I implement this in a pipeline with two stages, I could assign half of the initial cycle to the first stage, and half to the second, getting an improvement of 2x when the number of instructions is large, say 10**6. `with_pipe = 200 * 999999 + 400; without_pipe = 400 * 999999 + 400; with_pipe / without_pipe` gives you ~.5

Comment: @giuscri you seem to be working on the assumption that doubling the pipeline stages allows you to double the clock speed, that simply isn't true.

Comment: @Andrew OK. I think I understand. If I have a clock cycle `c` for a 1-cycle CPU and `s` stages, setting the new clock cycle to `c / s` will fundamentally do a mean of all the stage times, which is tied down by the faster stages (e.g. reading/writing from registers). That would mean that the new clock won't last enough for the more expensive stages - say writing to memory(?). Thus, the improvement in the clock cycle is by a factor of *at most* `c / s` (in the degenerate case where all the stages take the same amount of time). In general the improvement is worse than that. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @giuscri In a single cycle system the total cycle time is limited by the longest path. With two cycles we need a mid point to put the split but the chances are it's not going to be exactly in the middle of the longest possible path. So the system speed is set by the slowest possible path through the slowest stage of the pipeline. If there was an ideal mid point you still need some means to hold the pipelined value at that point. So we need to add the setup and hold time of a register to the clock cycle. We've also made things bigger, that means more clock skew which further decreases speed.

Comment: @DaveTweed Mhn. And what happens if >20% are conditional branches to take? Can I get even worse?

Comment: Yes, it gets worse.

Answer (score 5):

If you are designing a hardware control system that is heavily dependent on a myriad of interrupt signals from various sensors and timers, a pipelined processor may seriously degrade the obtainable performance of the system.

Since interrupts cause immediate stacking and branching, what is currently in the pipe may need to be aborted and flushed, or the interrupt may be held off until the current pipe clears.

Neither is advantageous if the response time to the interrupt is critical.

In the worst case scenario, with random interrupts, a pipe-lined processor may actually cause the system to fail catastrophically.

Can a processor be designed to circumvent these issues? Possibly, but that does not answer your question as asked.

Comment: This is not a great example. While existing implementations might have the problems you describe, there's actually no *theoretical* reason that an external interrupt should require a pipeline flush, since the ISR has no dependencies on anything already in the pipe (and vice-versa). Exceptions generated by the software itself (arithmetic errors, bus errors, etc.) do require special handling, and I suppose that many, if not all, existing architectures lump external interrupts under general exception handling for convenience in implementation. But it isn't a requirement of pipelining *per se*.

Comment: @DaveTweed, I agree with you, the right processor may handle things differently, but the original question was "Are there any cases where single-cycle is better than pipelining?". As you have indicated, "While existing implementations might have the problems you describe" I stand by my answer to the question asked.

Comment: @DaveTweed, good point though, thanks. I augmented my answer.

Comment: @Trevor How would a single-cycle CPU solve this?

Comment: @giuscri a single cycle CPU does not present the latency overhead associated with prefetching and caching instructions. Pipes are great for long linear code blocks. The caching benefits drop off rapidly for heavily branching, multi-path, code. There comes a point when that latency actually makes things slower than not having a pipe at all.

Comment: Dave Tweed makes a great point about interrupts and pipeline flushes. If anyone wants to study a classic case, just examine the DEC Alpha's design. That system KEPT so much instruction state that I decided I would ***NOT*** attempt to write an operating system for it. (Scared the bejeebus out of me.) It kept pretty much the entire pipeline and you had to wade through it before restarting.

Comment: Oh. And to complicate the discussion here further, let me introduce also VLIW and some of the optimization offerings developed as a result of the Bulldog compiler (Ph.D. thesis aka 1985, as I recall) which, for example, would pull code above conditional code edges and throw away results if the branch didn't go as predicted. Helped to fill functional units, though.

Answer (score 3):

One advantage of a single-cycle CPU over a pipelined CPU is predictability. This is important if you're using the processor for timing-critical operations, such as low-level "bit-banging" or real-time processing.

An example is the Sitara processor used by the Beaglebone. In addition to the main ARM processor, the chip contains two PRU (programmable real-time unit) microcontrollers, which have a single-cycle implementation instead of pipelined. (Details in [this presentation](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/images/3/34/Sitara_boot_camp_pru-module1-hw-overview.pdf).) Since each instruction predictably takes 5ns, you can ensure that real-time requirements are met.

Comment: I would think that for systems where pipeline delays would naturally be consistent, having multiple threads with a fixed round-robin execution would allow the design advantages of pipelining with the advantages of having two or more logical and independent cores.  I think that's what the Parallax propeller does, though I've never used it.

Comment: @supercat: No, the Propeller actually has 8 separate physical cores, each running at 80 MHz (IIRC). Each one has about 2K of private memory, and they share access to something like 32K of global memory using a fixed round-robin arbiter. What you're talking about is more like "hyperthreading" on Intel CPUs, where instructions from two separate "virtual cores" are interleaved in the same physical pipeline.

Comment: @DaveTweed: By my understanding, hyperthreading as done by Intel switches threads at indeterminate times.  I was thinking in terms of a CPU design that would e.g. have a 4-layer pipeline, and replace each bit of each register replaced with four chained flops, the first of which has a mux so it can capture either the output from the last flop or a value from a bus.  If all relevant data paths are normalized to have exactly four flops in them, the hardware requirement would be much smaller than would be needed for four CPU cores.

Comment: @DaveTweed: Essentially, all that would be necessary to increase the number of cores would be to add more flops to the system, and doing that would--up to  a point--make it possible to reduce the length of each pipeline stage.  Beyond a certain point, it would become necessary to replace memories arrays with smaller ones whose outputs can be latched before a mux to select them, but if having multiple cores running at the same speed would be useful, that could be a price/performance win.

Comment: @supercat: Are you maybe thinking of a [barrel processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/barrel_processor)? The barrel processors from XMOS or Ubicom or CDC execute [ "multiple threads with a fixed round-robin execution" with consistent, predictable delays, which is useful for timing-critical operations.

Comment: @davidcary: I think that's the term I was looking for.  Flip flops are pretty cheap especially when they can be placed back to back, so I would think that if a program has enough stuff to do to keep all the threads busy a barrel processor should be able to allow good price/performance in cases not needing too much memory.

Comment: @supercat - a more modern design that works in a similar way is the [UltraSPARC T1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraSPARC_T1).  It's a very interesting idea... which is why I've ended up doing something similar in [one of my current projects](https://hackaday.io/project/159826-io881).

Comment: @Jules: Looks cute.  Some vintage devices like the Commodore SID chip seem like they could have benefited from the barrel-processor philosophy; I wonder if any other sound chips in fact used shift registers along with a single set of ALUs (possibly even using short ALUs).  A fairly simple sound chip running off an 4MHz clock could generate eight channels of SID-style audio at a sample rate of 31.25KHz using 16-bit phase accumulators using only a single-bit ALU, with no per-channel circuitry other than shift-register bits.

Answer (score 2):

Dave gets it right, but his examples are hard to follow imo.

Pipelining is the trade-off between throughput and latency. If you pipeline, you've added latency.

A simple example: if you have a DIVIDE function that takes 4 pipeline cycles and an ADD function that takes 1 pipeline cycle, but all operations have to go through the entire pipeline to get to the output, ADDs would now take 4 cycles rather than 1. The advantage of this pipeline is that if you were dividing lots of things, after 3 cycles, you could get 1 DIVIDE happening every clock cycle whereas without a pipeline, you could only get 1 DIVIDE every 4 clocks.

We've traded 3 clock cycles of latency in the ADD function for higher DIVIDE throughput after the pipeline gets going.

Note that this example is simplistic and any hardware architect would try and find ways around the latency penalty for the ADD function, but this is the basic idea of the tradeoff pipelines give.

Comment: OK. But in the single-clock cicle I would have needed to adjust the clock cycle time to the time taken by the DIVIDE instruction, right? So I couldn't executed the ADD in 1 clock cycle anyway.

Comment: @giuscri Why would you waste your clock like that? If you can pump out an instruction in 1 clock cycle, why would you decimate that to 4? Just because one instruction implemented as fast as it could go took 4 clock cycles doesn't mean you need your entire cpu to run at that slow crawl.

Comment: In this thread I'm assuming we're executing one instruction per cycle. Meaning that in a single-clock cycle architecture you have to set the clock time to the operation that takes the most, otherwise instructions like `add $1, $2, $3` will execute, while `lw $2, 32($7)` won't as it involves a memory read.

Comment: @giuscri For very basic RISC architectures, that may be a valid assumption, otherwise, that's nowhere near realistic.

Comment: I omitted I'm talking about MIPS. I edited the question.